# clear interval doesn't work

Tags: jquery, clearinterval

iam using this code to animate a slideshow

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* slider initiate */
var timer = setInterval(slider,5000);

});
/* slider code */

var position = 0;
function slider() {
$('.slider .thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
position += 660;

var newPosition = position * (-1) + 'px';
if (position == 1980) {
    position = 0;
    newPosition = '0px';
}
var index = position / 660;
$('.slider .thumbs a').eq(index).addClass('selected');
$('.slider .slider-container').animate({left: newPosition}, 1000);
}
    /* click animation */
$('.slider .thumbs a').click(function(){
$('.slider .thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
var index = $(this).index();
var newPosition = index * (-660) +'px';
$('.slider .slider-container').animate({left: newPosition}, 1000);
clearInterval(timer);
var timer = setInterval(slider,5000);
});
```

but when i click on the thumbs the timer only accelerate that means that clearInterval doesn't work 
that happens too when i try to clear it on hover

Comment: @EoiFirst yeah the browser says that when i try to inspect it 
but wt is th solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a scope problem.

I guess timer is undefined when you try to clear it (try to see with `console.log()`).

It accelerate because since you `clearInterval` on `undefined` value you clear nothing, and you have 2 interval running at once.

Define your first `timer` var outside the `$(document).ready` scope.

```
var timer;
$(document).ready(function() {
/* slider initiate */
timer = setInterval(slider,5000);    
});
```

Also, don't re-define `var timer` inside the `slider` func. Just re-use the one you declared before.

But before all, don't re-use `setInterval` inside `slide`. You launch an interval within an other interval. You should use `setTimeout` if you need to set it again.

**Conclusion**

This is enough. With `setTimeout` you don't need to cancel it since it trigger only once. Set another timeout while you need to and it will simulate a `setInterval` without the need of canceling it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
/* slider initiate */
    setTimeout(slider,5000);
});

 function slider() {
    // your code
    setTimeout(slider, 5000);
 }
```