# One div to start contents to fadeToggle and another div to stop fadeToggle animation using javascript setInterval Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, setinterval, clearinterval

My Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tmanundercover/62ap2/
CSS

```
#targetedDiv, #otherDiv {
    border: 1px solid;

}
```

HTML

```
<div id="targetedDiv">&nbsp<span id="fakeCursor">|</span></div>
<br>
<div id="otherDiv">click here to stop</div>
```

Javascript

```
var fakeCursorInterval;

function startCursor(){
    fakeCursorInterval = setInterval(function() {             
    $("#fakeCursor").fadeToggle("slow","swing");},20);
    console.log("starting",fakeCursorInterval);
}
function stopCursor() {
    clearInterval(fakeCursorInterval);
    console.log("stopping",fakeCursorInterval);
}

$("#targetedDiv").click(function(){fakeCursorInterval = startCursor()});
$("#otherDiv").click(function(){stopCursor()});
console.log("outside",fakeCursorInterval);
```

My issue is that the console.log in stopCursor shows the interval as undefined.

I have looked at this post:
[clear interval doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22665190/clear-interval-doesnt-work)

so i'm pretty sure this is a scope issue but I cannot figure it out my specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're overriding the interval variable in your click handler.

```
$("#targetedDiv").click(function(){fakeCursorInterval = startCursor()});
```

This alone should work:

```
$("#targetedDiv").click(startCursor);
$("#otherDiv").click(stopCursor);
```

Comment: Good catch! I made that change in my jsfiddle but clicking the "otherDiv" div does not stop the cursor but, at least I get the same fakeCursorInterval ID from the console.log now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the issue mentioned by **@koala_dev**, the `setInterval` interval was `20`, the `fadeToggle` interval was `slow` (which is `600`). So, if you call `stopCursor()` after 1 second (1000 milliseconds), the `fadeToggle` would have been called 50 times. In that case, the fade animation will still last for 30 seconds (even that the setInterval have already been cleared). To resolve that issue, just use the same duration for both `fadeToggle` and `setInterval` (eg. `400` milliseconds). Additionally, you can call `.stop()` to stop the fade animation at the `stopCursor()`, and guarantee that it will really stop.

```
var fakeCursorInterval;

function startCursor() {
    $("#fakeCursor").show().fadeToggle(400, "swing");
    fakeCursorInterval = setInterval(function() {             
        $("#fakeCursor").fadeToggle(400,"swing");
    }, 400);
    console.log("starting", fakeCursorInterval);
}
function stopCursor() {
    clearInterval(fakeCursorInterval);
    $("#fakeCursor").hide().stop();
    console.log("stopping", fakeCursorInterval);
}
$("#targetedDiv").click(startCursor);
$("#otherDiv").click(stopCursor);
console.log("outside", fakeCursorInterval);
```

[**See fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/EAtPc/)